# Ubuntu Windows 8 Dual boot GRUB Unknown File system error

Tags: 14.04, grub2

After shrinking and increasing the size of a disk in Windows 8 .... this is the error that i get when i start up my PC , it says .... Entering GRUB Rescue Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that the filesystem containing Ubuntu had been moved in the process and GRUB could not locate it. All I did was to locate the correct filesystem and set it as root and voila!

Steps:

1. Search the filesystems by using `ls` command.

   ```
   ls
   ```
2. Look for a filesystem that is recognized by GRUB.

   ```
   ls (hd0,msdos6) {in my case , its msdos6}
   ```
3. Set root to that filesystem.

   ```
   set root=(hd0,msdos6)
   set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
   insmod normal 
   normal
   ```

This did work, but every time I restart I need to type the same thing over and over.
Hope it helps !!

Comment: you should be able to fix that by running `sudo update-grub` from ubuntu